# date difference in terms of days using mongotemplate

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have 3 columns in my mongodb named as `days (long)`, `startDate (java.util.Date)`, `endDate (java.util.Date)`. What all I want to fetch the records between startDate and `(endDate-days)` OR `(endDate-startDate)` <= days.
Can you please let me know how could i achieve this using mongoTemplate spring.

I don't want to fetch all the records from table and then resolve this on java side since in future my table may have million of records.

Thanks
Jitender

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in the query on the DB side (the end minus start part).   What I recommend if this is an important feature for your application is that you alter the schema to maintain in the document the delta between the two fields in the format you need it.   Since you can update that field when you update endDate (or if you populate both dates at the same time you can just compute the field then).

If you receive this data in bulk from another source, or if you do multi-updates of the endDate then you will probably need another job to run and periodically compute the delta of the documents where it's not computed (then you can start with always setting delta to 99999 and update it in this job to accurate value once endDate is set).

While you can use $where clause, it will be a very slow full collection scan so I would not suggest its use - it's probably better to come up with a more performant alternative even if it requires altering the schema.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/